# can't run xcodeproj

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

So I am trying to run the example xcode project [here](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView). However, I can't seem to run this. When I press run it just says build succeeded and didn't launch the app? Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GMGridView project builds a library, not an app, so there's nothing to run. There's also an Example project included which builds an app.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change target from GridView to GridViewExample (right next to run stop buttons).
Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

Run GMGridViewExample.xcodeproj, the other project just builds a static library.

Answer (score 0):

Who do you think you are, just asking us to run random code on our...oh alright, just this once. The example ran for me. Be sure to set it to run on the simulator.